# AuthHttp doesn't send post payload

Tags: angular, angular2-jwt, authhttp

I was using angular 4's default `Http` module to send http request without any problem. However, I recently replaced the `Http` module with `AuthHttp` from `angular2-jwt` package. Now with `AuthHttp`, it stopped sending body as payload to the server in post request. Here is the code:

```
return this.authHttp.post(url, JSON.stringify(body)).map((res: Response) => {
    // ...
});
```

The code above doesn't send the body as payload to the server. It sends the payload as expected when authHttp is replaced with http.

Not sure if I have done something wrong because it seems there's very few google results about this question.

Update:

With `AuthHttp`, Chrome Dev Tools shows only an `OPTIONS` request was sent . That's really weird.

Seems AuthHttp is sending some weird OPTIONS request to the server. Chrome shows the following error:

```
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding the following code on the server:

```
if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
    return
}
```